# Call jQuery function when element appears after page load

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery extension that gives custom scroll bars. Normally it would be called like this:

```
$("#thoughtsArticle #recentPosts").mCustomScrollbar();
```

But in this case the element that needs to be affected doesn't exist when the page loads. It appears as a result of user input. How can I execute this jQuery when the element appears on the page?

From googling I've figured out I need to use delegated events but I've not found any examples that I could directly apply in my case. Most examples were for events like form submission etc.

EDIT:

I don't think I've explained properly what I'm looking for. If you look at my [webpage here](http://rlcoaching.com), when the page loads, the 'blog' section doesn't exist. If you click on My Blog in the navigation bar, it will reload only a section of the page using AJAX. You will see on the blog section that I have a Recent Posts block on the right. I want to apply the custom scroll bar to that section.

The code I posted above is currently in the `$(document ).ready()` script with the rest of the jQuery, but as the target element doesn't exist on page load, the custom scroll bar is not applied.

I've tried putting a `<script>` tag on the blog page with the above jQuery, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I've searched a bit on the net and I think what I need to use is a delegated event? Not sure but either way I don't know how to use that in this case as none of the examples I could find would seem to apply in my case.

Comment: share some code that you have tried with html.

Comment: Execute your code line after you append the required element.

Comment: After the page load, is basically document ready. Once you DOM is prepared, you can simply call it on `$('document').ready(function() { });`

Comment: @ShaunakD I've tried putting that in a <script> tag after that bit in question has been loaded. I'm going to update the question with my website as I feel I've not expressed myself correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will fire when document is fully loaded. It will then add the delegate on document that will apply `.mCustomScrollbar();` I am a bit concerned will it fire 'ready' after that point thought, but you could try some other lifecycle event, or apply it without delegation immediately, as it is likely that your control is already on the page after document is ready.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('ready','#thoughtsArticle #recentPosts',function(){
        $(this).mCustomScrollbar();
    })
})
```

Comment: I've tried your code but unfortunately I can't get it to work. I don't know if I've placed it at the right point. I've put in the *$('document').ready(function() { });* on my index page, with the rest of the jQuery. If it's not too much to ask could you check my page's source to see if I have implemented it properly?

Comment: I've tried putting an alert('test') in your code to check. It appears it never gets called so the problem is not with the scrollbar extension.

Comment: `$(function(){` Is shortcut for document ready, only requirement is that JQuery is added before so put it at the bottom of the document and that should do it. Part that indeed might need tweaking is this `$(document).on('ready'` you might need to change ready to something else that gets fired when your control is added to the page.